# Route registration in laravel 5

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I’m a newbie in Laravel. Can you please enlighten me on how to register routes in RouteServiceProvider as I’m gonna have multiple route files for my project.
Thanks! Waiting in anticipation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you would register them in `routes.php` file. If you look at the source, all `RouteServiceProvider` does is just includes the `routes.php` file.

The syntax is *exactly* the same.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L41